# Is it possible to display an absolute child of a relative element outside of the relative element's box, if said box is overflow-y: auto?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, html-lists

I'm trying to represent a deep-nested folder structure as a clickable multi-level drop menu. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/jLQe8my.mp4) is a quick sample of what I have right now in action. Here's an HTML sample:

```
<div class="bookmark-container">
    <ul class="bookmark-list">
        <li class="folder">
            <a href="#" class="folder-title">TITLE</a>
            <ul class="root inactive">
                <li class="subfolder inactive">
                    <a href="#" class="subfolder-title">TITLE</a>
                    <ul class="subroot inactive">
                        <li class="file inactive">FILE</li>
                        <li class="file inactive">FILE</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="file inactive">FILE</li>
                <li class="file inactive">FILE</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is a made out of nested `<ul>` elements representing folders and subfolders, and `<li>` elements representing files. Here's the CSS for that HTML:

```
.folder, .subfolder {
    position: relative;
}
.root, .subroot {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
}
.subroot {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Until now this actually works perfectly. With JavaScript I can show and hide the nested `<ul>` elements on click of the `<li>` element they're a child of and it's all awesome. However, if I throw:

```
ul {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Which I need to represent folders larger than what my viewport can handle, the absolute positioned `.subroot` elements aren't visible anymore, since their visibility outside of their relative parent hangs on the fact that it can overflow. [This](https://i.imgur.com/qfYt8dF.mp4) is the result with scrolling vertical overflow.

I can already kinda see where the problem is. I need to change the parent element that has either the `overflow-y: auto;` or the `position: relative;` properties, so that the `position: absolute;` child is able to overflow, but I've been playing with adding `<div>`s and other elements in between and changing the CSS property targets, and nothing seems to work yet.